# Is it possible to target Amazon's affiliate program to the user's country?

Tags: affiliate, amazon, country-specific

I have signed up for Amazon's affiliate program, to see how well it does. However, the program appears to be specific to each of Amazon's separate sites (Amazon.com, .co.uk, .ca etc).

Around 50% of the traffic comes from the USA but there is a significant proportion from Canada and the UK too. Is there any system from Amazon to target products to the user's country? Or must I do this myself?

Comment: this might be useful: http://affiliate-blog.amazon.co.uk/2007/03/earn_money_worl.html

Comment: If you figured out the answer to your question, can you close it or flag it for close please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but Amazon does not help you with this. I use this on [Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com).

Once **registered with all the Amazon programs of your choice** you need to use each of them to create the banners you need.

It is **easiest if you use categories** (Electronics, Books, DVDs, etc) instead of products (BBC Earth, Lord of the Rings DVD, etc) because there is more chances of having something that matches on multiple sites.

Categories do not always exist though, for example one Amazon will put cameras in the Photo category and another will put it in Electronics. Also, MP3s and Downloads only exist in some places.

**Put the generated banners somewhere such as database along with the country code.** Each time a visitor arrives on your site use a Geolocation API (Downloaded a PHP one) to get the user's country code and query for a banner that matches.

If there is no match, you can show nothing, show your preferred one (Amazon US actually ships some products internationally but not most) or backill from another affiliate program that works everything, such as a software download or online service.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** If you have the technical ability, you should be able to adapt https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io to meet your needs.

Another possibility is Stephen Morley's PHP class http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/mapping-visitor-ip-addresses-to-amazon-sites/ The php class allows you to Geo target your users, it also lets you target them by the language they are using. Unfortunately, the database hasn't been updated for quite some time. If there is no product in their local store for the product of interest it will default to the main store (or whatever store you put as your default).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a web service called [A-FWD](http://a-fwd.com/) that enables you to create links that work with all Amazon stores.

That way you don't need to install a plugin or javascript on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this yourself using visitors IP address.

http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/221159-increase-amazon-conversions-rate-geo-targeting.html

Comment: The link doesn't add anything, but thanks. I'll look into some geo-targeting or something.