# Amazon affiliate and multilanguage

Tags: multilingual, affiliate, amazon

I do not know where else to post this question, I hope this StackExchange site is the right one.

I have a multi-language site (blog), with several reviews pointing to amazon affiliate product page. My issue is about which country version (.it, .de, .com, and so on) the link should target.

The majority of my articles are in italian, and the link point to amazon.it affiliate homepage.

As far as I have understood, the various .it, .de, .com, .co.uk version are separated and so are the affiliate programs.

Let's say I have an article in English, it could be visited from an Italian, a German, or a US Citizen.

Which amazon affiliate page should I link on that page? (Spamming the page with all the links of all the amazon sites does not seem viable, too many links can confuse the user.)

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to target Amazon's affiliate program to the user's country?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/7368/17633) (probably not a duplicate, as it’s about different countries, not languages)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect which country a user is from using their IP or potentially other identifiers and have your site serve the ad which is relevant to them.